# Is it possible to query archived records for a batch delete?

Tags: apex, soql, batch, archive

We've recently built a full sandbox and realized that our storage is over 130% capacity.  Some digging found that there were 7million tasks taking up 94% of our storage.  In order to use the sandbox, we opted for a BatchDelete class which was able to take care of about 3million tasks, and deleting the org Recycling Bin along the way.  I was trying to work out why I couldn't tackle the remaining ~3million, and realized through a workbench soql in production that they were archived.

Some research shows that archived tasks cannot be accessed through normal soql query, only queryAll.  My attempts so far have not allowed queryall to be compatible with the database.  I also read that ALL ROWS might work, but has only seemed to return already deleted results.

Is it possible to adjust the class so that I can retrieve the archived tasks?

```
public with sharing class BatchDeleteTasks implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

     public final String query;

     public BatchDeleteTasks() {
         query = 'SELECT Id FROM TASK WHERE SUBJECT LIKE \'%Email%\' LIMIT 50000';

     }

     public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext bc) {
         return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
     }

     public void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<SObject> scope) {
         delete scope;
     }

     public void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
     }
 }
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried with this [Querying All Records with a SOQL Statement](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_SOQL_query_all_rows.htm) ?

Comment: ALL ROWS returns deleted and archived; you can filter out the IsDeleted ones

Comment: @SubratSrivastava yes, that has returned "First error: Delete failed. First exception on row 0; first error: ENTITY_IS_DELETED, entity is deleted: []"

Comment: @cropredy I'll try adding a filter for the isDeleted, thanks!